# How to use styled Components with Material UI Icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I tried using the override "!" but that still didnt work, is there a way to style it? Everywhere I looked online couldnt help.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import styled from 'styled-components';
    import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
    
    export default function Search() {
      return (
        <Form>
          <SearchBar
            type='text'
            placeholder='Have a question? Search for answers…'
          />
          <MagnifyIcon />
        </Form>
      );
    }
    
    const SearchBar = styled.input``;
    
    const Form = styled.form``;
    
    const MagnifyIcon = styled(SearchIcon)`
      background-color: 'blue';
    `;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase specifity with the following code.

```
<MagnifyIcon className={'override'} />

const MagnifyIcon = styled(SearchIcon)`
    &.override{
            background-color: 'blue';
        }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this without having to have a class name in the icon, you can use the `&&` operator instead:

```
const MagnifyIcon = styled(SearchIcon)`
    &&{
            background-color: 'blue';
      }
`
```

And use the icon like this:

```
<MagnifyIcon />
```

Comment: It looks like you have a typo. `background-color: blue;` is correct css syntax.